# How to retrieve event.json file to unit test lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, sam

I am able to run AWS lambda using postman. I want to use the event to run unit test along it. I am not sure how I can generate the event.json file.

I tried logging event that I receive in my handleRequest method on cloudwatch logs but it does not seem to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the Lambda event structures in the documentation. Here is the list for all the different event types, [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event).

In your case I would say the event you are looking for coming from API Gateway, you can find it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event

Comment: I am looking for a way to autogenerate the event.json in aws if I am running my endpoint using API Gateway. Thank you